# How do I ensure I always get a list of matches from Python's Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex, tuples, findall

I'm trying to pull some information (no recursion necessary) from a jsp page (malformed xml) similar to this:

```
<td>
<html:button ...></html:button>
<html:submit ...></html:submit></td>
```

And a regex:

```
<html:(button|submit|cancel)[\s\S]*?</html:(button|submit|cancel)>
```

re.findall() is giving me a list of tuples, like so:

```
[('button','button'),('button','button')]
```

Which I understand from the documentation is correct, but I'm looking to get something more like:

```
["<html:button ...>","<html:button ...>"]
```

What is the appropriate way to get the outcome I expect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ;) Well, maybe for this simple case regex might be appropriate ... but bobince's posting is worth reading all the same.

Comment: You don't want to continue trying to do this.  You really must stop trying to write regular expressions for HTML and start using Beautiful Soup.  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll give everything a try tomorrow when I'm back at work. I will try to calm everyone's fears by mentioning that I'm not trying to do anything like match tags - because it's malformed xml, the tags just happen make convenient markers for the beginning and end of the information I need, they don't need to match at all. The lack of a closing end-bracket on the open tag in my example is actually intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(button|submit|cancel)` getting capture, so add `?:` in brackets like `(?:`

```
>>> re.findall('<html:(?:button|submit|cancel)[\s\S]*?</html:(?:button|submit|cancel)>',TheHTMLWhichShouldntParseWithRegex)
['<html:button ...></html:button>', '<html:submit ...></html:submit>']
```

Comment: This is actually exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you kindly. Though, I think I'll take S.Lott's suggestion and check out Beautiful Soup, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact that a regex probably isn't what you want to do this with, you want to put the bit you want in groups using parentheses. If you want everything up to the closing `</html:whatever>` tag, then you want something like this:

```
(<html:(button|submit|cancel)[\s\S]*?)</html:(button|submit|cancel)>
```

If you just want the `<html:button>` bit, use:

```
(<html:(button|submit|cancel)>)[\s\S]*?</html:(button|submit|cancel)>
```

e.g.

from

```
<html:button>foobar</html:submit>
```

you get:

```
('<html:button>', 'button', 'submit')
```

If you want to get the `foobar` from above, use:

```
(<html:(button|submit|cancel)>)([\s\S]*?)</html:(button|submit|cancel)>
```

to get:

```
('<html:button>', 'button', 'foobar', 'submit')
```

Note that it is not, in general, possible to match opening and closing tags (note that `<html:button>` is opened, and `</html:submit>` closes in the example above). If you need to do that, use a proper parser.

Comment: Ah, Yours seems to get more nearest to OP sample, +1